# A question on '주체높임법 (subject honorific)'

Tags: honorific, difference

How and when to use the honorific in Korean is one of the most difficult and confusing things in learning Korean. Let's imagine the below situation where your father tells you to ask your grandfather to come over. Which sentence would be correct to use and why?

Speaker: 나 (myself)

Listener: 할아버지 (my grandfather)

Asker: 아버지 (my father)

> 1. 할아버지, 아버지가 이쪽으로 오래요.
> 2. 할아버지, 아버지가 이쪽으로 **오시래요**.
> 3. 할아버지, 아버지**께서** 이쪽으로 오래요.
> 4. 할아버지, 아버지**께서** 이쪽으로 **오시래요**.

If the listener and asker are changed, would there be any difference? In other words, your grandfather tells you to ask your father to come over.

> 1. 아버지, 할아버지가 이쪽으로 오래요.
> 2. 아버지, 할아버지가 이쪽으로 **오시래요**.
> 3. 아버지, 할아버지**께서** 이쪽으로 오래요.
> 4. 아버지, 할아버지**께서** 이쪽으로 **오시래요**.

Answer (score 3):

If we want to show respect to someone who does something, we put 시 to the verb. But if the listener has higher rank than the person who is acting, we don't put 시. The situation is the same for 께서.

오래요 is a combination of 오라고 and 해요. In the first case, the second sentence is correct because 오시래요 is a combination of 오시라고 and 해요. In the second case, none of them are correct. The correct sentence is

> 아버지, 할아버지께서 이쪽으로 오라셔요.

Here, 오라셔요 is a combination of 오라고 and 하세요.

By the way, I feel it's too formal to use 께서 between family members. I want to use instead

> 아버지, 할아버지가 이쪽으로 오라셔요.

Answer (score 2):

in first question, correct is '2. 할아버지, 아버지가 이쪽으로 오시래요'. 
because grandfather is more high position in family structure, then if you description to your father's saying or act, cannot use honorific words.
'가' is normal word, and '께서' is honorific. and '오래요' is normal word, and '오시래요' is honorific.

and second question correct answer is '3.아버지, 할아버지께서 이쪽으로 오래요.'
reason is same that first question.